# how to store data in mvc for using it the across application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In my application When user Login at that time I want store some information of user like firstname, lastname, Id, employee Id, etc. which I want to use at many places in my web application.
Previously I was using form Authentication

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(empDetails.Employee.EmployeeId, false);
```

But It stores only one parameter. I want to store multiple data which I will use in my application.

Can any one tell me the best way to do this.

Comment: if you know who is logged in, cant you just look in the database for the other details they gave when they signed up and store it in a session / cookie?

Comment: Yes I can but I don't want to look in the database every time I want same data. E.g. I want FirstName of user at many places in my application (about 10-12 places), for this every time I have to query in database to get Firstname, instead of doing this I would like to store some data when user login & use that data every where.

Answer (score 1):

The auth cookie can be used to save a string. This string can encode all the data you want.
I usually create an object (e.g. ConnectedUser class) that has all the information I want saved. I then override the ToString() of the class to return a string in a fomrat that I can later decode to reconstruct the ConnectedUser instance. This is even made easier if all your models inherit from a single basemodel, then the basemodel can have a property of type ConnectedUser, then you can extend the DefaultModelBinder and override OnModelUpdated() to reconstruct the instance of connected user.  Usually I do this through a method that accepts the requestcontext, like that I can call it from elsewhere in the code if the modelbinder has not been called for some reason.

EDIT

```
    public class ConnectedUser{

        public string FirstName{get;set;}
        public string LastName{get;set;}
        public override string ToString(){
            return string.format("FirstName{0}{1}{2}LastName{0}{3}",EqualDelimiter, FirstName, EntryDelimiter, LastName);
        }
     }
```

And now in the constructor of the Auth cookie instead of passing in userId, you pass it an instance of ConnectedUser with FirstName and LastName filled in. When a request is received you can retrieve the connected user with these 2 methods which can be called from the custom extension of defaultModelBinder or inside an action method, etc.

```
    public static ConnectedUser GetConnectedUser(HttpContextBase executingContext)
    {
            var dictionary = GetAuthCookieData(executingContext);
            var toRet = new ConnectedUser
            {
                FirstName = dictionary["FirstName"],
                LastName= dictionary["LastName"]
            }
            return toRet;
     }
     public static IDictionary<string, string> GetAuthCookieData(HttpContextBase executingContext)
    {
        HttpCookie toCheck = executingContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        FormsAuthenticationTicket decrypted = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(toCheck.Value);
        string userData = decrypted.UserData;
        return userData.ToDictionary<string, string>();
    }
```

Extending the DefaultModelBinder should be straight forward just don't forget to register it in Global.asax.  There are plenty of articles online on how to do both.

Comment: Can you please give me some example or reference of it.

Answer (score 1):

For your problem I would suggest storing your value in  `HTTPCOntext.Current.Session`

First create a class like this

```
    public class CurrentCustomer
    {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }

            private string _Token;
            public string Token
            {
                get
                {
                    return _Token;
                }
                set
                {
                    _Token = value;
                }
            }
     }
```

Then after logging in of the user (means when the user is authorized)
fetch all your required data fill your CurrentCustomer object and then create your Seeion like this

```
HttpContext.Current.Session[CurrentCustomer] = CurrentCustomer;
```

And now wherever you need that value Create your CUrrentCUstomer Object.

```
CurrentCustomr obj = ((CurrentCustomer)HttpContext.Current.Session[CurrentCustomer]);
```

Thats all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could store a JSON string with all parameters you want:

```
{name:"NAME",id:"IDENTIFIER",email:"EMAIL"}
```

Then parse it on restore.